# Copy Paste with VBA and a List

Tags: vba, list, excel

I am quite new to VBA and I can't find a proper way to solve my following problem.

I have an Excel Workbook with 5 worksheets. The last 3 worksheets are full of data, while the first one is a list with the names of the 3 last worksheets inside it. I want that when I select on the list a name of one of these worksheets, it is copy pasted to the second worksheet which is empty.

Let's say, I select worksheet 4 in the list, worksheet 2 is now a copy paste of the worksheet 4.

Comment: Recording a macro will get you most of the way there...

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sure: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html

Comment: [Step 1 - Start with the macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Step-1-Start-with-the-macro-recorder-6DC53056-1DE1-4483-AA07-63E4E0EFE3C2).

Comment: Thank you, I will check and I come back to you!

Comment: it work well! But I need to make a button, any idea how to automatize it? When I put it in Sheet1's code, its not working since it need to go on other sheets.

Comment: Once you have written the macro you can add a shape, like a rectangle, then right click and select `assign macro` and choose the macro you have recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this into Sheet1 's  code module. 
Change these:

1. Sheet2Name
2. Sheet1NamesListAddress
3. NewName

   ```html
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
       Const Sheet2Name = "Sheet2"
       Const Sheet1NamesListAddress = "A1:A10"
       Const NewName = "New Name"

       If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(Sheet1NamesListAddress)) Is Nothing Then
           Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           On Error Resume Next
           Sheets(Target.Text).Copy Before:=Sheets(2)
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Target.Text).Delete
           Sheets(2).Name = NewName
           Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           On Error GoTo 0
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you all for you answers. It went well with the macro recorder. 
Just to finish, I have two questions. 

1 - I need to do a button for that because, if I put it in Sheet1 code's module, its not working. Is there any way to do it automatically? 

2 - Thanks Thomas for the code. If now I want to have my name on the list different from the name of the worksheet I copy. Lets say the name in the list is A and it will copy the worksheet called "AA1", how should I do? 

Cheers

Comment: Make sure that you are using Sheet1.  The VBA Project window shows the Sheet code name as well as it's Sheet name. This example Sheet3(Sheet2) is referring to Sheet3.

Comment: you can add a button via developer tab in Excel ribbon > insert.  But first you must allow developer tab to show , from File>options>customize ribbon>on the left panel , click developer.